# Simple examples of proper holomorphic submersions whose fibers are not biholomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, fiber-bundles, several-complex-variables

[This MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/56737/69037) features an example of a proper holomorphic submersion whose fibers are not biholomorphic. If I understand correctly, the example is that of elliptic curves fibered by their $j$-invariant. I haven't learned any of that story yet, so I'm wandering if there are simpler examples.

**Question.** What are some simple examples of proper holomorphic submersions whose fibers are not biholomorphic?

Comment: I think this is the simplest example you will find.

Comment: Here is another example (of higher genus), due to Kodaira: Start with the product $M=S\times S$ of a compact Riemann surface of genus $\ge 2$. Let $f: S\to S$ be a fixed-point free biholomorphic map and $F\subset M$ be the graph of $f$. Then $F$ is disjoint from the diagonal $D$ in $M$. Let $N\to M$ denote the 2-fold ramified covering, ramified over $D\cup F$. Then $N$ admits a holomorphic submersion $N\to S$ (composition $N\to M\to S$) whose fibers are not all biholomorphic to each other.